# jQuery or CSS Problem?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm using this code to make `#sidebar`'s height match `#post_content`'s height:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$().ready(function(){
   $('#sidebar').height($('#post_content').outerHeight(true)); 
});
</script>
```

This works on the homepage: http://themeforward.com/demo2/ and even on a posts page without comments... but once comments are added they no longer match heights: http://themeforward.com/demo2/2011/01/02/centered-and-captioned-image-longer-title/

To illustrate the problem I have made the post_content div background color black and the sidebar background color gray.

Here is my CSS:

```
#container {
    width:1126px;
    margin:35px auto;
    padding:0;
    background:#000;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden
}
#sidebar {
    display:inline-block;
    float:right!important;
    width:410px;
    padding:0 0 0 25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#AAA;
    border-left:1px solid #EEE
}
```

Here is my comments.php:

```
<?php

// Do not delete these lines
if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
die ('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');

if ( post_password_required() ) { ?>
<p class="nocomments">This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.</p>
<?php
return;
}
?>

<!-- You can start editing here. -->

<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
<div class="responses"><?php comments_number('No Responses', 'One Response', '% Responses' );?> to &#8220;<?php the_title(); ?>&#8221;<?php if ( comments_open() && ( 4 <= get_comments_number()) ) : ?>
<a href="#respond">»</a>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div id="commentlist">
<ul>
<?php wp_list_comments('avatar_size=60'); ?>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="more_posts_comments">
<div class="oe"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
<div class="re"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
</div>

<?php else : // this is displayed if there are no comments so far ?>

<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>
<!-- If comments are open, but there are no comments. -->

<?php else : // comments are closed ?>
<!-- If comments are closed. -->
<p class="nocomments">Comments are closed.</p>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>

<!-- Respond to this -->
<div id="respond">
<div class="responses"><?php comment_form_title( 'Leave a Reply', 'Leave a Reply to %s' ); ?></div>
<div class="cancel_comment">
<?php cancel_comment_reply_link('cancel comment'); ?>
</div>


<?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
<p>You must be <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>">logged in</a> to post a comment.</p>
<?php else : ?>

<form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">

<!-- If the user is logged in... -->
<?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>

<div class="logged-in"><p>Logged in as <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a> - <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="Log out of this account">Log out</a></p></div>

<?php else : ?>

<!-- If the user isn't logged in, they need to fill out these forms... -->
<div id="small_forms">
<input type="text" onfocus="clearDefault(this)" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Name (required)';" value="Name (required)" name="author" id="author" size="22" tabindex="1" />
<input type="text" onfocus="clearDefault(this)" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='E-Mail (required, hidden)';" value="E-Mail (required, hidden)" name="email" id="email" size="22" tabindex="2" />
<input type="text" onfocus="clearDefault(this)" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Website';" value="Website" name="url" id="url" size="22" tabindex="3" />
</div>

<?php endif; ?>

<div id="submit_spacer"><h6><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea></h6></div>

<!-- Submit button -->
<h6><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Comment" class="submit" /></h6>

<h6><?php comment_id_fields(); ?></h6>

<?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>

</form>

<?php endif; // If registration required and not logged in ?>
</div>

<?php endif; // if you delete this the sky will fall on your head ?>
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the same effect with pure css by positioning your sidebar absolutely to the container div. Try this:

add:

```
#container {
   position:relative;
}

#sidebar {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: +1. This is probably the best solution since he doesn't need #container to be anything other than position:relative;

Comment: There is one problem with this... it cuts off content in the sidebar if the page or post content is shorter than the sidebar.  Is there a way to dynamically resize an absolutely positioned div?

Comment: You're hiding the content that comes after with "overflow:hidden"..try this: remove the overflow:hidden from your container id and your sidebar id, introduce a clearfix and add a clearfix class to your container, i always use this one: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/ ... then go ahead try what i posted above, i just tested it out and it works fine.

Comment: [screeshot](http://i.imgur.com/QOHGy.jpg) .. i removed almost all the content up to the image in your test post.

Comment: This doesn't actually work, the absolute positioning of the sidebar expands past the footer and the color doesn't follow through. http://themeforward.com/demo2/2011/01/03/title-of-post/

Comment: You're not properly containing the elements in your html, just place everything inside your container div, that way you can manipulate everything as it should be, thats what that container is for.

Comment: It works for me when I add some stuff. #container { position: relative; } #sidebar_wrap { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; } #sidebar { height: 100%; }

Comment: @skyuzo you're basically doing the same thing ive been noting, just adding the attributes to a different div. The sidebar_wrap div can totally be dismissed and deleted as it is just extra markup, all those attributes can be added tot the sidebar div.

Comment: Yeah. #sidebar_wrap is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Am I missing something here?  Everything is in the container div, isn't it?  But it still does this: http://themeforward.com/demo2/2011/07/08/link/

Comment: I don't see Andres' additions to your #container and #sidebar.

Comment: I've added clearfix as a class to container and sidebar for my single posts (which is where I'm testing this).  I must be missing something?
http://themeforward.com/demo2/2011/07/08/link/

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something. I don't see anything wrong with that page. I only see something wrong with http://themeforward.com/demo2/

Comment: At themeforward.com/demo2 the sidebar expands the entire size of the container as it is supposed to.

At my link http://themeforward.com/demo2/2011/07/08/link/ the sidebar expands past the container.

Comment: I see.. that's very confusing behavior to me. Just curious: Why does the sidebar get clipped when it's not as tall as the container? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Fell asleep last night and woke up to look at your page, everything is so weird now :D

Comment: @LucasWynne if you're still stuck here's a nice little article that can get you started on something, i would advice you to forgo the jQuery route as that to me is not the right tool for the job, simple CSS can handle all that. Anyways, here is the article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: @Andres - is there a way to get a absolutely positioned div (the sidebar) to have it expand its height so it doesn't cut off the content.  I know about the "faux columns" method but it seems like there should be a CSS workaround.  Cut-off content: http://themeforward.com/demo2/2011/07/08/link/

Comment: Just took a look at your page, its looking good!, i made a template for you that you can use that works better and does exactly what you're looking for. Here is the demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/andresilich/5T45P/show/ ...... and here is the main fiddle page:http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/5T45P/ .. check it out and let me know if anything.

Answer (score 0):

Make un function that set the height.
For example:

```
function setHeight(){
    $('#sidebar').height($('#post_content').outerHeight(true)+'px');
}
```

Call this function on page ready 
and call it back again when you added content in #post_content.

Comment: You can also call that function within a `resize()` event handler. Then, you won't need to keep track of when its size changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a clearfix element to do this for you instead? That way you don't have to dynamically track when the height changes. You need to use it in combination with a false background though.

On another note, shouldn't it be $(function() { }) or $(document).ready(function() { }) $().ready(function() { }) is not recommended.

Comment: I don't think a clearfix will help. He wants to have the sidebar resized to the full height of the container, not have the container resize to the full height of the floated children.

Comment: I tried clearfix already, it doesn't.  Thanks for the help though!